# Prove that $|u(x,t)|\leq\sup\limits_{y\in R^n}|g(y)|$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let 
>   $$u(x,t)=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(x-y,t)g(y)dy$$
>   where 
>   $$\Phi(x-y,t)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}}$$
>   (this is the solution for the homogeneous heat equation), where $g$ is a continuous function with $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}g(x)=0$. Prove that $$|u(x,t)|\leq\sup\limits_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n}|g(y)|$$
>   for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n, t>0$.

My Attempt:

For a fixed $x,t$, we have

$$e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}}\leq 1$$

Hence
\begin{aligned}
\lvert u(x,t)\rvert &\leq\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n} \lvert \Phi(x-y)g(y) \rvert dy \\
        &=\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|\Phi(x-y)||g(y)|dy\\
        &\leq\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}} \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}|g(y)|dy\\
        &\leq \sup\limits_{y\in \mathbb{R}^n}|g(y)|\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}dy
\end{aligned}
But after that how can I get rid of the integral?

Comment: What do you know about $g$?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur sorry. I forgot to include that..  I edited the question just now. It is continuous with zero limit at infinity

Comment: Doesn't the heat kernel $\Phi$ have some sort of constant (depending on the dimension) in front of it as well as $|x-y|^2$? I remember the proof using the fact that the heat kernel resembles a gaussian, which is a known integral.

Comment: @F.Conrad yes you are right. I added that too. Sorry but even with that constant I don't see a suitable simplification

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh.. I have missed an important lemma. 
[image]
This is from the book: 
Partial differential equations
Book by Lawrence C. Evans second edition page 46

So with that It will solve the problem.