# Prove that $ \lim_{t\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x,t)| = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Consider the initial value problem: 
>   $$ \left\{
>  \begin{aligned}  u_{t}-\Delta u &=0 \quad \text{in}~ \mathbb{R}^n
>  \times (0,\infty) \\  u &=g \quad \text{on}~ \mathbb{R}^n \times \{
>  t=0 \} \end{aligned} \right. $$ 
>   And the solution:
>   $$ u(x,t) = \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}
>  \Phi(x-y,t) g(y)\,d y $$
>   Where
>   $$\Phi(x-y,t)=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}}$$
>   Assume that $g$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^n$, with $\displaystyle \lim_{|x|\to \infty}g(x)=0$. 
>   Prove that:
>   (a) $\displaystyle |u(x,t)| \leq \sup_{y\in\mathbb{R}^n} |g(y)|$ for
>   all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$, $t>0$
>   (b) $\displaystyle \lim_{t\to\infty} \sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}^n}|u(x,t)| = 0$.

**My attempt:**
Part (a) is done [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3562207/prove-that-ux-t-leq-sup-limits-y-in-rngy). I mentioned it in the question because I'm not sure whether that is also necessary for the part(b)

Now for part (b),
\begin{aligned}
|u(x,t)| &= \int\limits_{\mathbb{R}^n}
 \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} |g(y)|\,d y\\
&\leq \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}\int\limits_{R^n}|g(y)|dy\quad\quad\text{ $\because$ $e^k$ is non negative for any $k\in R$}
\end{aligned}
So from here if I can show that the integral of $g$ exists in $R^n$ (as a finite number) then it will give the result. May be for this I will need to use the given data that $g$ vanishes for large $x$. But I don't see how to  do that.

Or may be there is a totally different way.
Appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you missed a square in the formula of the heat kernel
$$ \Phi(x-y,t) = \frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{n/2}}e^{-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}}$$
For your questions, if $g\in L^1$ then we can solve it as following: $|g|\leq C$ and 
\begin{align}
u(x,t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y,t)g(y)\;dy &\leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi^2(x-y,t)\;dy\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} g^2(y)\;dy\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\leq \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi^2(x-y,t)\;dy\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} C|g(y)|\;dy\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\\
&\leq \sqrt{C}\Vert g\Vert_{L^1}^{1/2} \frac{1}{(8\pi t)^{n/2}} \underbrace{\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi\left(x-y,\frac{t}{2}\right)\;dy\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}}_{1}
\end{align}
Therefore the conclusion follows.

Now your assumption does not imply that $g\in L^1$, as 
$$ g(x) = \frac{1}{|x|+1} \notin L^1.$$
Nevertheless, we can approximate $g$ by compactly supported functions. Let $r_k\rightarrow \infty$ such that 
$$ \sup_{|x|\geq r_k} |g(x)| < \frac{1}{2^k}$$
Let $g_k(x) = g(x)\chi_{B(0,r_k)}(x)$, then $g\in L^1$ and $|g|\leq C$.
Let $u_k(x,t)$ be the solution with initial data $g_k$, then it is easy to see that
\begin{align}
|u_k(x,t) - u(x,t)| &\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} \Phi(x-y,t)|g_k(y) - g(y)|\;dy\\
&\leq \int_{\mathbb{R}^n\backslash B(0,r_k)} \Phi(x-y,t)|g_k(y)|\;dy \leq \frac{1}{2^k}.
\end{align}
Let $t\rightarrow \infty$, we see the conclusion.

Comment: Thank you  very much

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think the way I have thought was not correct.
We can say, $g$ is bounded because it vanishes at large $x$ and continuous.  (if it becomes unbounded in the middle then it cannot have zero limit in the end due to continuity)

So we can take $g$ out from the denominator. After that we can solve the remaining integral as mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3564238/evaluate-int-limits-rne-frac-x-y4tdy)