# evaluate $\int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} \, dy$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

> for a fixed $x\in\mathbb R^n$ and $t>0$, 
>   evaluate $$ \int\limits_{\mathbb R^n}e^{\frac{-|x-y|}{4t}} \, dy$$

I see that when taking the modulus, then the above integral has the format of an integral on Real  line. Hence it will be like, finding $$\int\limits_{\mathbb R} e^{\frac{-w}{4t}} \, dw$$ 
for $w\geq 0$ which I can possibly do. 
But I wonder whether that is the correct way of seeing it?

Comment: Yes. The property you're talking about is called translation invariance.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much!